# run sh script in jmeter

Tags: bash, jmeter

For load testing I want to randomize my testvalues before I run the test in jmeter. To do so, I want to use this bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash
cat data.dsv | shuf > randomdata.dsv
```

This should be executed in jmeter. I tried using a BeanShell Sampler with this command (I am using this command to always find the correct paht to the file no matter on which machine I want to execute it):

```
execute(${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}random.sh)
```

but I always get this error message:

```
ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   In file: inline evaluation of: ``execute(/home/user/git/path/'' Encountered "( /" at line 1, column 8.
```

Any Ideas what to do or is there some best practice I just di not found yet?

Comment: Is that `execute(/home/user/git/path` a snippet from your user's shell initialization scripts or something by and chance?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would suggest going for [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) instead, it should be easier to use, something like:

[image: OS Process Sampler Example Configuration]

In regards to Beanshell approach, there is no need to us __Beanshell function in the Beanshell sampler, besides an instance of Beanshell interpreter is created each time you call the function causing performance overhead. You can just put the code into sampler's "Script" area as

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
FileServer fileServer = FileServer.getFileServer();
command.append(fileServer.getBaseDir());
command.append(System.getProperty("file.separator"));
command.append("random.sh");
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.toString());
int returnValue = process.waitFor();
return String.valueOf(returnValue);
```

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but with these links (I tried the OS Process Sampler as well) I was sadly unable to complete what I want. I realy don't know why there seems to be no easy example for this case. Am I trying something so strange here?

Comment: You may need to provide full path to shell interpreter and full path to your script in the OS Process sampler like `/bin/bash /opt/jmeter/bin/random.sh`, it should do the trick for you. Please let me know if I should update the answer with OS Process Sampler screenshot

Comment: Thank you for all the attention! I would really appreciate if you could show me a screenshot of the OS Process Sampler.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the screenshot, feel free to substitute Working directory and parameter as required